# Como definir melhos nomes para entidades do sistema?

Tags: banco-de-dados, orientação-a-objetos, design-pattern

Como definir melhor nomes para as entidades do meu sistema.
Eu tenho uma tabela usuário.
E tenho uma tabela redefinir_senha onde relaciono informações do processo de redefinição de senha (id, hash, data_expiração_link, senha_redefinida, nova_senha, is_usuario, estado)
No meu sistema eu tenho o modelo redefinir_senha_vo.class.php
Eu aprendi que nomes mais adequados para classes seriam os substantivos em uma especificação de sistema.
E esse nome "redefinir_senha" não é um substantivo ?
Sobre essa estrutura mencionada, alguma dica ?
Alguma dica sobre quala melhor forma de definir as  entidades e modelos do sistema ?

Comment: Corre um sério risco dessa pergunta ser fechada, por isso vou expressar minha **opinião** em comentário, isso é muito relativo, e na verdade até existem alguns "padrões" com questões de nomeação de entidades, _namespaces_ e etc. E ainda existe algumas "conveções" para cada linguagem, por isso não citarei nenhuma, mas o que costumo utilizar em PHP é substantivos no plural e em inglês, ou seja, `Users`, `Products`, `CartProducts`; No teu caso para "redefinir senhas" eu usaria algo como `RePasswords` ou `NewPasswords` ou `RedefinedPasswords` e isso vai ao padrão do projeto ou desenvolvedor.

Comment: Redefinir_senha não seria um comportamento de uma classe chamada senha ?
E entidade não deveria chamar-se log_senha ?
Não seria mais plausível ?
A idéia era apenas filosofar a respeito.

Comment: no caso de uma hierarquia de herança, poderia ter uma classe base, chamada log, onde log_senha iria herdar de log.
Sacou /

Comment: Na pergunta tu fala apenas da questão de nomeação das entidades, por isso não entrei em detalhes de arquitetura/desenvolvimento, mas pra mim "redefinir_senha" seria uma ação da entidade `Users`, e como já são registrados log's sobre a entidade `Users`, então não me preocuparia com `log_senha`, já que eu "teria" `log_users`.

Comment: Mas log user não teria os atributos de log_senha.
Daí a verdadeira utilizade de normalização de banco de dados.
Nesse contexto, você consegueria me ajudar KaduAmaral ?

Comment: Então pra mim esse "log_senha" seria `RePasswords { int id; int userId; string oldPassword; string newPassword; date created; int status; bool defined; }` -> ID, Usuário, Senha Antiga, Nova Senha, data da "solicitação",, situação, definido. Meu padrão seria mais ou menos esse, para o teu caso.